# First hitting probability to $+1$ of a symmetric random walk if we start at $0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk

The following is an interview question taken from Mark Joshi's Quant Job Interview.

> Question: Given a fair coin. I gain one on a head and lose one on a tail. I quit when my position is $+1$. What is the probability that the game terminates?

I think it assumes that we start at $0$?

Also, I think this question is related to first hitting probability of a symmetric random walk. But I have no idea how to start at all.

Comment: yes this is also known as gamblers ruin.  It has been discussed many times e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497645/showing-that-p-k-frackk-1p-k-1-forall-k-implies-p-k-frackn/3498747  A simple take: truncate so that 'you' must quit when you are up 1 or have lost 'b' and find probabilities of winning here.  Now take limits of the sequence of stopping thresholds b, b+1 , b+2... and note the probability of winning is monotone increasing and bounded above by 1.  Another approach is to directly do this with the PGF/OGF for the hitting time distribution

Comment: This is the unbiased random walk on the integers, not gambler's ruin. The game terminates with probability one but the expected time to termination is infinite. See e.g. *Adventures in Stochastic Processes* by Resnick.

Comment: @Math1000 Perhaps you can provide more details on how to get probability one?

Comment: @Math1000 you said "This is the unbiased random walk on the integers, not gambler's ruin" but *many* sources say this *is* gamblers ruin e.g. here is the first result that came up under a search http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-GR.pdf It is also sometimes people refer to this as gamblers ruin with an infinitely rich player (or adversary).  To be clear I have no issue calling it a simple symmetric random walk.  But I also have not issue with my statement "this is also known as gamblers ruin"

Answer (score 1):

This is a symmetric random walk, which returns to zero infinitely often, hence the game ends with probability 1.

Let $x_k$ be the probability of ending (winning) the game, given that we have $k$ coins.

Assuming that we start with zero coins, we are interested in computing $x_0$.

Now, the following holds for $k\le 0$:

$$x_n = \frac12 x_{n+1} + \frac12 x_{n-1}  $$

with $x_1 = 1$ and $x_k >0$ for $k\le 0$.

It's easy to show that $x_k=1$ is the only solution.